# PhpStorm phpmd custom ruleset

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpmd

I did the following

1. Download PHP Mess Detector Plugin
2. Choose a PHP Interpreter (Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> CLI Interpeter
3. Made sure that my Mess Detector Plugin is setup is properly and has a Interpreter assigned, that has phpmd installed. (Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Mess Detector -> Configuration -> Click on ... -> Click on Validate

But when I go to Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Inspections -> PHP Mess Detector validation and try to add a Custom ruleset I get the following message:

> "Custom rules are not supported for current interpreter"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to define the Interpreter as "Visible only for this project"

To do so go by:

Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Click on ... next to CLI Interpeter -> and make sure that "Visible only for this project" is checked. Then you can select your custom PHPMD ruleset.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not help